# buildbot auto build nginx fail

Tags: nginx, automated-tests, buildbot

I've set up a buildbot, trying to use to build nginx.

But I fail which auto "configure" as nginx's './configure' is in ./auto/ which usually is in ./ .

My factory config is shown as below:

```
nginx_factory.addStep(Git(repourl='/home/hanc/data/git_data/nginx_1.5.8', mode='incremental', method='fresh'))
nginx_factory.addStep(Configure(command=["./auto/configure --without-http_rewrite_module --without-http_gzip_module"]))
nginx_factory.addStep(ShellCommand(command=["make", "-j2"]))
```

The error message is:

```
Upon execvpe ./auto/configure --without-http_rewrite_module --without-http_gzip_module ['./auto/configure --without-http_rewrite_module --without-http_gzip_module'] in environment id 27183840
:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 420, in _fork
    executable, args, environment)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 466, in _execChild
    os.execvpe(executable, args, environment)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 353, in execvpe
    _execvpe(file, args, env)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 368, in _execvpe
    func(file, *argrest)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've noticed it said file not found. But the file is there correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to set the workdir variable in the ShellCommand definition to build/nginx_1.5.8 (check the slave folder structure)